# ALL shortest paths between a given node and a destination

Tags: c, graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

I want an algorithm to find ALL the shortest paths between source S and destination E. I know that Dijkstra's algorithm can find one of the shortest paths, but I'm stuck at finding an algorithm for all the shortest paths using an adjacency matrix and BFS (breadth first search) in C.

Comment: There are algorithms to find *all* paths. Collect them all, and then pick out the "shortest".

Comment: if you know Dijkstra, you can edit the alogrithm such that it doesn't terminate after finding the destination once. Just keep a list of nodes you already visited and keep expanding nodes until all edges have been visited. Stop a path whenever you arrive at a node you already saw. In that way you should be able to fins all shortest paths from A to B

Comment: You mean, between all destinations find ALL the shortest path, right? That is virtually impossible, that is also known as the traveling salesman problem or the NP-hard solution. Once you increase the destination the computation grows at factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#:~:text=The%20travelling%20salesman%20problem%20(also,returns%20to%20the%20origin%20city%3F%22